# Code for bouncing emails using Amazon SES and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm able to send the emails to my recipients using Amazon SES service with Node.js but I'm unable to see if the emails are bouncing back if I enter a wrong recipients emailIDs.

Please let me know if I need to add something to get the bounce back response.

I am sending the email using the following code:

```
app.get('/emailData', function (req, res) {
  var emailfrom = "sender@example.com";
  var emailto = "receiver@example.com";

  var ses_mail = "From: 'AWS' <" + emailfrom + ">\n";
  ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " + emailto + "\n";


  var params = {
    RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer(ses_mail) },
    Destinations: [ emailto ],
  };

  ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err);
    } 
    else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  )};        
});
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't detect that when sending the email; you would have to use an imap library and regularly check for incoming emails about the outgoing one bouncing back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Amazon SES Notifications in order to monitor bounce or complaint events. You cannot get immediate feedback when sending (`ses.sendRawEmail` doesn't error).

> Amazon SES can notify you of bounce or complaint events in three ways: by sending a notification email, by notifying an Amazon SNS topic, or by publishing sending events.

You can have Amazon SES notify a SNS topic in case of a bounce event and have a Lambda function subscribe to this topic. This way you can implement you own logic in case of a bounce.

See [Monitoring Using Amazon SES Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-using-notifications.html).